# Help making my villain who wants to rid my D&D world of all magic

Tags: dnd-5e, campaign-development, villain, ending-campaigns

So, who I plan on making the big bad of my current campaign (a powerful wizard who tapped into the magic of the void and is almost invincible [ofc not really cause they need to be beatable] when it comes to magic), I want to give the goal of trying to absorb and 'delete' all magic in the universe other than themselves, making them the sole magic user and holder. But, this is D&D and I want a huge epic final battle and it will be hard with no magic! Basically, what this villain is doing is going under the guise of this omniscient being that stops really powerful magic disasters (that they put into play) so that they can convince everyone to reject magic (all magics arcane and divine). But I just don't know what to do to keep this idea going, I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Welcome to the stack! Please take our [tour] to learn more about how we operate. Unfortunately, this question may be closed as opinion based. This is more of a discussion than a Q&A, but once you have 20 rep you can hop into [chat] where we may be able to help guide you.

Comment: I have a similar villain planned in my campaign, maybe my thoughts help you. I based him on Thanos from avangers. Basically Thanos wants to kill half of all population because he things he saves people this way. Similarly my villain wants to remove all magic to protect people. The adventure starts with the lost mines of phandelver, because the mknes were lost during a big wizardinf war that left big scars and destruction on the landscape as only magic can do. My villain has his magic from items, that the players can take from him during the fight. Or find them before he does.